# Why was my stock purchase rejected on TD Web broker?

Tags: stocks

I am attempting to purchase 6,000 shares of a micro cap company listed on the
TSX-V exchange.

Total shares outstanding 120 million

Shares float 30 million

Bid .34  0 lots

Ask .395 0 lots

I understand there are no shares available at the moment, so I placed an order on TD Web Broker for 6,000 shares with a limit at .395 but it got rejected.

I was under the impression the order would sit in the system until a seller decided to fill it..

What am I missing?

EDIT: I adjusted the order to .40 and this time it was cancelled instead of rejected

Thx

Comment: Markets are closed today, but for my brokerages that just means orders sit until next market day, I'd assume same from TD, but was it a "good for day" order or "good 'til cancelled" order?

Comment: Hello,
At first I set it for expiry tomorrow, next attempt I adjusted it to “good til day” - same result

Comment: I added an edit to my question, I adjusted the purchase order to .40 from .395 and it was cancelled, not rejected, this time.